# Can we publish a pubnub message synchronously using Java sdk

Tags: pubnub

We are writing a messaging app in Java . By default pubnub Java sdk supporting publish a message asynchronously. We are using pubnub 3.7.10 version.

but we want to publish messages using pubnub synchronously . How can we achieve this ??

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## PubNub Publish Sync

If you can wait a week or two [for v4.0 of the PubNub SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/pubnub-java-sdk-v4), it is super simple to do sync publishing. It is currently in beta2 but no changes are planned before GA in the next week.

```
pubNub.publish().message(Arrays.asList({'msg':'hello', 'sender':'user123'})).channel("my_channel").sync();
```

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/api-reference-sdk-v4#publish

Comment: PubNub Java SDK 4.x is GA now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Please refer to [PubNub publish not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037507/pubnub-publish-not-working) post that has the complete code showing how you can make a synchronous publish with PubNub 4.0 SDK version.