# PubNub publish not working

Tags: pubnub

I am trying to integrate PubNub with KaaIoT platform where the publish API is throwing the following error/exception:

[image]

Following is the code showing a sample message that I am trying to publish:

```
PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
        pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey("sub-c-7c052466-04ea-11e5-aefa-0619f8945XXX");
        pnConfiguration.setPublishKey("pub-c-12a0e504-b46c-4c9c-ba5d-089ae589bYYY");

        PubNub pubNub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);

        try {
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("value", "39");
            data.put("since", "07:00 AM");

            pubNub.publish()
                    .message(data)
                    .channel("TEMP")
                    .sync();

            System.exit(0);

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Got PubNubException..." + ex.toString());
            throw ex;
        }
```

If I try this above sample code as a standalone application, it is working fine. However, inside kaaiot, it is not working. And, I am not able to make out much from the log.

Any idea what might be causing the sync method to fail?

Comment: can ypu try the exec() method instead of sync()

Comment: Publish does not have execute() method. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/api-reference-sdk-v4#publish

Comment: Could it happen due to conflict with other JARs?

Comment: Sorry, not `exec`, I meant `async`. See sample code here: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/api-reference-sdk-v4#publish_basic_usage

Comment: Even async fails with the same exception

Answer (score 1):

Can you call any other rest based endpoint? The SDK is making rest calls under the covers. The log, although not very informative, seems to point to not being able to make a rest call.

It also maybe kaaiot, do they allow generic http request?

Comment: I tried to fetch a simple Google Search result using Apache HttpClient and it works.